# Elementary make my laptop's fans stop working

Tags: macbook, laptop

I downloaded elementary two days ago, and some things have been doing even stranger things to my 2014 macbook air.

1. My fan stopped working
   My computer will not break a sweat, even under the largest loads. It will get really really hot and just throttle.
2. It won't sleep properly
   Now I have to charge my computer when left unattended, because if I don't it will just lock me out. It won't even turn the screen off when I shut the lid.

So, if any of you have the same problem, or are looking fix it, please offer help.

Thank you,
Arence

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook   Use that wiki as a guide for any problem you may have with your laptop. The only disadvantage is that you can't install any package from the AUR but you could try to `sudo apt install [package] ` . 

Also, it's recommended to install TLP  `sudo apt install tlp `.

Answer (score 1):

I run elementaryOS on my MacBook Air from 2013.

I had similar issues, here is what i did:

Installed macfanctld (a service that manages the Exhaustfan of the MacBook) and psensor to read live the current temps and RPM of the fan.

The cool thing is: macfantld has a config file in /etc/macfantld (when installed of course) that you can edit and when macfanctld reads its config it changes the rpm of the fan.

Here is the link to my github, i made a little script that allows me to change the rpm of the exhaust fan to 3 settings (low - mid - high) and then a value that i want.

https://github.com/BookerVII/ExhaustFanSpeedControlforMacfanctld

download (install) the macfantld, psensor and the script, run the script with sudo ./rpm_script.rev0.4 (low mid high or set 0-6500)

Maybe that will help :)

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac Mini i use mbpfan under Kubuntu its by far the best solution I know to get fans correctly working on Macs. It's not easy to setup but heres an tutorial to get it working an a Mac:

[a-beginners-tutorial-for-mbpfan-under-ubuntu](https://ineed.coffee/3838/a-beginners-tutorial-for-mbpfan-under-ubuntu/)